# Sorttable How does it work?

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui-sortable

I have an HTML table with less than 50 rows.
I am using [Sorttable](http://www.kryogenix.org/code/browser/sorttable/) to allow the users to sort the table accordingly.

I would like to stripe my tables with something like: [Zebra Tables](http://validweb.nl/articles/better-zebra-tables/)

I have implemented both scripts on the table. The only problem is that I need to call the stripe method after the table is sorted.

I am unsure how the Sorttable script is called, as there isn't a onclick method added to the header of my table.

So my question is, how can javascript be called without an event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at line 92 of sorttables.js. Its adding a click event:

```
dean_addEvent(headrow[i],"click", function(e) {
```